# Positioning Stack children in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a stack widget, the first child is an image which is limited to height 320 and width 240. The next child is a text widget. And I'm building this dynamically based on total number of elements in my list (of name and image) using the .map() function.

I want to set the name(text) to the center of the image. The text is of variable length and we can hard-code position of one particular name but not for all.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far.

Comment: I simply tried the positioned() widget. The problem is if I set left: 50 then one of the text might be centered but not all.

Comment: If you provide the code, others can understand your layout and edit it to solve the issue. There's not much that can be done without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the alignment property of `Stack` to center it:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 240,
          height: 320,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        Text("Some Text"),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Though a `Container` should be enough:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 240,
      height: 320,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/240/320"),
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Some Text"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```